# Keep track of warnings without always doing a full rebuild

Tags: .net, jenkins, msbuild

We have a large C# project that generates a lot of warnings (shame on us). We are using our CI server (Jenkins) to track the number of warnings in a graph. Hopefully we can start slowly reducing the number of warnings.

When we create a full rebuild all of the warnings show up. However a full rebuild can take over 40 minutes. A normal incremental build takes around 7 minutes however this displays only the warning in the projects that have changed. This means that more often than not the total number of warnings displayed in Jenkins is wrong.

I was wondering if there is any way to keep track of warnings and which projects they where in? For example: if project A has 3 warnings and was not touched in the last build we can assume those 3 warnings are still there.